# How is RISC-V neg instruction implemented?

Tags: assembly, riscv, instructions, riscv32

How is the `neg` pseudo instruction implemented with only one sub?

I don't understand, as `neg` is `R[rd] = -R[rs1]`. But if I have `sub`, it is `R[rs1] - something`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "something" in this case is the `zero` register. but you're not subtracting that from the register, you're subtracting the register from *that.*

The:

```
neg rd, rs
```

pseudo-instruction is meant to put the negation of `rs` into `rd`. The

```
sub rd, zero, rs
```

instruction subtracts `rs` from `zero`, placing the result into `rd`.

```
rd := -rs        ; example: -(42)  -> -42
rd := 0 - rs     ;          0 - 42 -> -42
```

Since `-x` is the same as `0 - x`, they are equivalent.

---

If you want a more comprehensive list of pseudo instructions and what they map to, here an image which details some, including the specific one you asked about:

[image]